# How can I put the sysdate into the ttitle in Oracle SQLPlus reports?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report, sqlplus

I'm currently trying to put the sysdate into the `ttitle` element of a SQLPlus report, but I can't quite get the syntax right.

This is what I have to far:

Can anyone help?

```
ttitle center 'This is my title' skip 2 left -
              'prepared by a SQLPlus noob' right -
              select sysdate from dual skip 4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [new_value](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/new_value.html) construct in sqlplus to do this.

```
SQL> set feedback off;
SQL> column a1 new_value report_date
SQL> select sysdate report_date
  2    from dual;

SQL> spool "C:\report1.log"
SQL> select * from scott.emp;
SQL> spool off;
```

Report output

```
Sat Nov 26                                                                                                                                                                                     page    1
this is the employee report for 26-Nov-2011

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO                                                                                                                   
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------                                                                                                                   
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20                                                                                                                   
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30                                                                                                                   
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30                                                                                                                   
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20                                                                                                                   
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400         30                                                                                                                   
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                    30                                                                                                                   
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10                                                                                                                   
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20                                                                                                                   
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10                                                                                                                   
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0         30                                                                                                                   
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20                                                                                                                   
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                    30                                                                                                                   
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20                                                                                                                   
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                    10
```